# PHP - how to show Posted ad first in minutes,then hours,then days,then months

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site in which user posts the statuses.
I am saving the datetime along with the status in the database, the type is `datetime`.

Once an user posts the status from any part of the world, it should show first how many minutes ago the status was posted, then it should show in hours after 60 mins, after 24 hours it should show in days.
And then months and years.

How can I do all this calculation and print the result. 
If anyone worked on this please share the code.
I have no idea how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
function time_elapsed_string($added_on)
{
    $etime = time() - $added_on;

    if ($etime < 1)
    {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array( 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'month',
                      24 * 60 * 60  =>  'day',
                           60 * 60  =>  'hour',
                                60  =>  'minute',
                                 1  =>  'second'
                );
    $a_plural = array( 'year'   => 'years',
                       'month'  => 'months',
                       'day'    => 'days',
                       'hour'   => 'hours',
                       'minute' => 'minutes',
                       'second' => 'seconds'
                );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1)
        {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r . ' ' . ($r > 1 ? $a_plural[$str] : $str) . ' ago';
        }
    }
}
```

$added_on variable your format must be strtotime(date format Y-m-d h:i:s)

Comment: could you tell me what is $ptime? and why $added_on variable when we are not using it anwhere? and please also tell me how would be the time format?

Comment: Thanks. one last thing. what is the time format of $added_on. could you defined $added_on variable before the function so I should know how I should send the time in this variable.

Comment: it isn't working. when I use this time 2015-8-26 04:00:00. it gives me 46 years ago message

Answer (score 0):

raveenanigam solution is not bad, but it is in PHP which is not what you want I guess. I think that this solution may fit your purposes.

1.- Print with php the timestamp into an attribute like... for example this:

```
<span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="<?php printMyTimestamp(); ?>"></span>
```

2.- Just paste this in a JS file and import it to your HTML. Make sure you imported JQuery before.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // Search all the timestamps
    var timestamps = $(".timestamp");

    timestamps.each( function(i) {
        var element = $(this);
        var timer = setTimeout(function() {
          var time_elapsed = $.now() - element.attr('timestamp');
          var msg = "";

          if (time_elapsed < 60000) {
              msg = "less than one minute ago.";
          } else if (time_elapsed < 3600000) {
              msg = Math.floor(time_elapsed / 60000) + " minute(s) ago.";
          } else {
              msg = Math.floor( (time_elapsed / 60000) / 60) + " hour(s) ago.";
          }

          element.empty().append(msg);
          timer = setTimeout(arguments.callee, 60000)
    }, 200);
});
```

Here you have a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8grhvo5/

**IMPORTANT: PHP time() function prints the time in seconds, while JS prints it in milliseconds, so, a workaround to solve this would be this:**

```
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

Feel free to add more messages like days, months, years...

NOTE: This way is dynamic and it works without making hundreds of requests. This only needs one request and the datetime is saved as an attirbute and calculated client-side. The PHP way requires a new request every time you want to see the elapsed time.